# SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync returns SignInStatus.Failure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, asp.net-identity, owin, google-api-dotnet-client

In my mixed MVC and WebAPI project, I tried to OAuth users via google, it returns SignInStatus as **Failure** always. I don't know why and also I wonder even with failure status, the template code (from Microsoft) in ExternalLoginCallback() method for `SignInStatus.Failure` status is redirecting to a page with "Succesfully authenticated message".

I am trying this in a new test project and Owin libraries are latest.

Answer (score -1):

I just tried running the same code after sometime, it worked. Looks like google API needs sometime to update.